# Laravel How to sort Collection based on array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, collections

Basically title is the questions itself. I have a collection, which stores arrays in one of the field. I made a sorting algorithm to sort out those arrays and the result is sorted array:

```
array:8 [▼
  3 => array:5 [▼
    5 => 100
    1 => 50
    2 => 30
    3 => 20
    4 => 10
  ]
  6 => array:5 [▼
    1 => 100
    5 => 50
    3 => 30
    4 => 20
    2 => 10
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    3 => 100
    5 => 50
    4 => 30
    1 => 20
    2 => 10
  ]
```

The index of this array 3,6,2 is the ID of the collection. How can I order collection based on this ID's in same order as array ?

Comment: You need to use Sortby method of collection

check more in detail here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have array inside `$a` variable:

```
$a = array:8 [▼
      3 => array:5 [▼
        5 => 100
        1 => 50
        2 => 30
        3 => 20
        4 => 10
      ]
      6 => array:5 [▼
        1 => 100
        5 => 50
        3 => 30
        4 => 20
        2 => 10
      ]
      2 => array:5 [▼
        3 => 100
        5 => 50
        4 => 30
        1 => 20
        2 => 10
      ]
    ];
```

then you can sort in ascending order with reference of key from `ksort()` and have something like this:

```
foreach($a as $b)
{
    ksort($b);
}
```

and similarly for descending order you can use `krsort()`.

Hope this helps.